# Why does value not change inside thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

When i assign a new value to variable it doesn't change after start(), however after i use join() it does. Why does this happen and in this case should **int a** be volatile or not?

```
class SampleThread extends Thread {

    private static int a = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        a = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new SampleThread());
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the new thread to immediately get control before the main thread continues and executes `println`?  There's no guarantee on the order in which the threads get dispatched.

Comment: It does, but main thread continues with `System.out.println(a);` before second thread will change `a` (so change will happen *after* printing). To increase chances of second thread updating `a` before main thread will print it make that main thread wait for a bit before calling `println`. You can do it by invoking something like `Thread.sleep(1000);` before `System.out.println(a);`.

Comment: If 2 threads should be executed then it could be that only 1 thread is executed (main thread) before the JVM quits; To prevent this we could use join() so the JVM waits until 2nd thread is finished before terminating. Am i right?

Comment: If even one non-daemon thread is still active then JVM will not exit. Since your `t2` thread was not set to be a daemon then your application will exit only when *main* thread will finish and when `t2` will finish. `.join` is used when you want to force thread which calls that method to wait till other thread will finish its work. In your case if you call `t2.join()` inside `main` then main thread will wait till `t2` will finish its work and only after that will continue (but in that scenario it defeats the purpose of even starting separate thread).

Comment: If you explicitly `.join()` on `t2`, you don't need volatile - as joining a thread establishes a happens-before edge.

Answer (score 1):

for seeing what is going on, try this:

```
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start of Thread");
        a = 3;
        System.out.println("end of Thread");
    }
    ...
```

<sup>only `run` method changed, rest of code unchanged</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it needs volatile.

Every thread has an evil coin. The thread flips the coin anytime it reads or writes a field: Heads, and the thread uses its own local (to the thread) copy of it; if writing, that update simply does not reflect to all the other threads, who will still see the 'old' value, and if reading, same deal: Reads whatever it had, even though other threads updated it already. Even if they did so an hour ago. Tails, and it does refresh other threads' views of this thing, and won't use the local copy.

The coin is evil: it is not a fair coin. It will work every time today, and every time tomorrow, and every time during the test suite, and all throughout that week you have it live for the early adopting customers. And then juuust as that big client comes in and you're giving the demo? It flips to break your app every time. That kind of evil.

So, you must eliminate all coin flips, or at least ensure that the result of a coin flip **does not affect your app whatsoever**.

The way to do this, is to establish comes-before relationships. Between any 2 lines of java code as executed by a VM, there is a set of rules to determine if these 2 lines have such a relationship: That one is guaranteed to be run after the other. It's not about whether they did (timestamps of when they ran is completely irrelevant), it's whether the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) decrees that such a relationship exists.

If yes, no coin is flipped: Anything the 'line that came before as per the JMM' did, is definitely visible to the line that came after. But if the JMM does not explicitly spell out that this relationship exists, **the coin is flipped, and you lose**.

One trivial 'comes before' relation ship is within a single thread: `x = 5; System.out.println(x);` trivially has such a relationship; they ran in the same thread, one came after the other. That's the freebie.

But between threads, oh dear. You need `synchronized`, `volatile`, or call code that does these things internally or has other mechanisms to ensure it (tip: There is *lots* of great stuff in the java.util.concurrent package, and as the name suggests, it's generally thread safe in very efficient ways. For example, an `AtomicInteger` is almost always far better than a `volatile int`, and can do far more, such as CAS operations, which volatile ints cannot do.

Comment: If 2 threads should be executed then it could be that only 1 thread is executed (main thread) before the JVM quits; To prevent this we could use join() so the JVM waits until 2nd thread is finished before terminating. Am i right?

Comment: no, the VM does not quit until all threads* are done. *) if you set the 'daemon' flag on a thread, it won't count. There is no need to join here. Note that join is one way to establish comes-before. all statements thread X executes come before the resolution of `X.join()`. In that way, after joining, the variable is guaranteed updated. You need to read the JMM and the full list of CBCA rules, or forego communicating between threads via fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect things in different threads to happen in a particular order -- in this case, that `a = 2` is executed before `System.out.println(a)' -- then you have to write code to make that order happen.

In this trivial case, where no real work is being done, almost anything you can do makes the use of threads pointless.  The main thread could 'join' the thread that's setting `a` to 2, but then all you've achieved is an expensive way to execute code that could be executed in a single thread.

Comment: But this is obviously not for real applications, but for training purposes. So what you said really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

main thread should wait that the other was executed
One solution is to use join()

```
class SampleThread extends Thread {

    private static int a = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        a = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new SampleThread());
        t2.start();

        // wait for completion of t2
        t2.join()

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if value is not assigned inside t2 then why does the code in t2 immediatly fire? And does the JVM quit when a deamon thread is active?